# MySQL Data Lag in local application

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue that I cannot see to find a solution to.

We have a small server application that pings a GPS Server every 1o seconds and writes the values to two tables. Firstly `GPSLive`, secondly `GPSLog`. The server application reports the last time the data was updated for each table.

The client application reads `GPSLive` to draw a GPS map of the vehicles. The client checks the timestamp of the `GPSLive` table and compares it against the current time and warns the user that the data may not be current.

At the moment 18:12:22 the server has updated both rows at 18:11:59. However, the client is showing that the data is 16 minutes old.

The `GPSLive` table has a single row and is overwritten at every update. This happens regularly and will then catch up. The system runs on our local LAN only and at most has a handful of users. When I look at `GPSLive` via workbench I can see the timestamp hasn't updated.

Is there anything I can do to fix this behaviour?

**Edit: Added Code**

```
    Public Sub AddtoGPSLive(JSONString As String)
    Dim sql As String = "Update GPSLive Set GPSJSON=@J Where ID=1"
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.BMConnString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@J", JSONString)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                txtLastLive.Text = Now
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the setting of `autocommit`?  Do you do the updates inside a transaction?

Comment: I am not sure what setting `autocommit` is, I havent changed away from the default value. We dont use transactions. The code has been added above.